# Finding all restaurants at given lat/long in Python

Tags: python

This is a program I wrote to grab restaurants/bars from Google, Yelp, and Foursquare. It then ranks them more effectively based on the rating, the number of ratings, and the number of data sources using a Bayesian average. My guess is that the main method could be broken into more functions. I'm also guessing I'm missing some handy list comprehension tricks. Any suggestions?

#### main.py

```
import csv
import time

import foursquare
import yelp
import google


def bayesian(R, v, m, C):
    """
    Computes the Bayesian average for the given parameters

    :param R: Average rating for this business
    :param v: Number of ratings for this business
    :param m: Minimum ratings required
    :param C: Mean rating across the entire list
    :returns: Bayesian average
    """

    # Convert to floating point numbers
    R = float(R)
    v = float(v)
    m = float(m)
    C = float(C)

    return ((v / (v + m)) * R + (m / (v + m)) * C)


def remove_duplicate_names(full_list):
    """
    Fixes issue with multiple API calls returning the same businesses

    :param R: The entire unfiltered list
    :returns: Filtered list
    """

    names = set()
    filtered_list = []
    for business in full_list:
        if business.name not in names:
            filtered_list.append(business)
            names.add(business.name)

    return filtered_list


def main():
    """
    Finds all the bars/restaurants in the given area. Use different
    lat/long points to cover entire town since API calls have length limits.
    """

    input_value = ''
    locations = []

    distance = input('Search Radius (meters): ')
    while input_value is not 'n':
        lat = input('Lat: ')
        lng = input('Long: ')
        locations.append((lat, lng))
        input_value = raw_input('Would you like more points? (y/n) ')

    venues, businesses, places = [], [], []

    for lat,lng in locations:

        # Retrieve all businesses for all sources
        print 'Searching lat: {} long: {} ...'.format(lat, lng)
        venues.extend(foursquare.search(lat, lng, distance))
        businesses.extend(yelp.search(lat, lng, distance))
        places.extend(google.search(lat, lng, distance))

        # Rate-limit API calls
        time.sleep(1.0)

    # Remove duplicates from API call overlap
    venues = remove_duplicate_names(venues)
    businesses = remove_duplicate_names(businesses)
    places = remove_duplicate_names(places)

    # Calculate low threshold and average ratings
    fs_low = min(venue.rating_count for venue in venues)
    fs_avg = sum(venue.rating for venue in venues) / len(venues)

    yp_low = min(business.rating_count for business in businesses)
    yp_avg = sum(business.rating for business in businesses) / len(businesses)

    gp_low = min(place.rating_count for place in places)
    gp_avg = sum(place.rating for place in places) / len(places)

    # Add bayesian estimates to business objects
    for v in venues:
        v.bayesian = bayesian(v.rating, v.rating_count, fs_low, fs_avg)
    for b in businesses:
        b.bayesian = bayesian(b.rating * 2, b.rating_count, yp_low, yp_avg * 2)
    for p in places:
        p.bayesian = bayesian(p.rating * 2, p.rating_count, gp_low, gp_avg * 2)

    # Combine all lists into one
    full_list = []
    full_list.extend(venues)
    full_list.extend(businesses)
    full_list.extend(places)
    print 'Found {} total businesses!'.format(len(full_list))
    
    # Combine ratings of duplicates
    seen_addresses = set()
    filtered_list = []
    for business in full_list:
        if business.address not in seen_addresses:
            filtered_list.append(business)
            seen_addresses.add(business.address)
        else: 
            # Find duplicate in list
            for b in filtered_list:
                if b.address == business.address:
                    # Average bayesian ratings and update source count
                    new_rating = (b.bayesian + business.bayesian) / 2.0
                    b.bayesian = new_rating
                    b.source_count = b.source_count + 1
                 
    # Sort by Bayesian rating
    filtered_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.bayesian, reverse=True)

    # Write to .csv file
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:

        categories = ['Name', 'Rating', 'Number of Ratings', 'Checkins', 'Sources']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=categories)

        writer.writeheader()
        for venue in filtered_list:
            writer.writerow({'Name': venue.name.encode('utf-8'),
                             'Rating': '{0:.2f}'.format(venue.bayesian),
                             'Number of Ratings': venue.rating_count,
                             'Checkins': venue.checkin_count,
                             'Sources': venue.source_count})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Descriptive names**

The function signature is:

```
bayesian(R, v, m, C)
```

But then you go a long way describing these single letter parameters in the docstring:

```
:param R: Average rating for this business
:param v: Number of ratings for this business
:param m: Minimum ratings required
:param C: Mean rating across the entire list
```

Most usually, descriptive code is preferred over descriptive comments / docstrings for the simple reason that having two things (code / comments) instead of one (code) doubles the maintenance effort, and if code and comments get out of sync, the code becomes extremely confusing.

**Built-ins**

```
names = set()
filtered_list = []
for business in full_list:
    if business.name not in names:
        filtered_list.append(business)
        names.add(business.name)

return filtered_list
```

Becomes:

```
return list(set(business))
```

The code does not care about the order of the restaurants as far as I can see, so the fact that `set` changes order should not be a problem.

**Function for input**

Getting user input is a detail, when looking at the main structure of the program in `main` we don't care about it, so just use a function.

```
while input_value is not 'n':
    lat = input('Lat: ')
    lng = input('Long: ')
    locations.append((lat, lng))
    input_value = raw_input('Would you like more points? (y/n) ')
```

**No `input` in Python 2**

It automatically evaluates the input, it is dangerous to execute anything the user enters and universally considered bad practice. Use `int(raw_input(x))`

**The overload**

`+` means many things in Python, one of them is adding lists:

```
full_list = []
full_list.extend(venues)
full_list.extend(businesses)
full_list.extend(places)
```

Becomes:

```
full_list = venues + businesses + places
```

With a clear gain in clarity.

Comment: Thanks so much. Lots of great suggestions here. I appreciate it!

Comment: On your first point: The main reason I chose comments over descriptive variable names was because of the formula at the end. I think this might be an exception to your otherwise agreed upon rule. That formula is pulled directly from here -> http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?votestopfaq

Comment: Yes, mathematical formulas always are a gray area for naming ... I think that including a link to the original source would be the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few comments in addition to Caridorc's good comments:

- *Within `bayesian()` you convert to float, but before that you possibly use int* – When providing the parameters to this function you do some math, which could or could not be int operations. You might want to enforce the float at an earlier level
- *Change into a list of search engines* – Instead of duplicating your logic three times, I would change into storing the results in a list of list, and use a list of providers to keep addresses, search method, name of provider, and so on. This could simplify your logic, and would make it easier to extend to new providers.
- *No input validation* – What is the input format for latitude and longitude? I know there exists at least three or four different variants. Which variant is accepted by all of these search engines?
- *Split up into some more functions* – I like the way you call `main()` but I would have split it up into more functions, so it could read something like:

  ```
  def main():
     locations = get_location_list()
     restaurants = execute_search(locations, search_engines)
     rated_restaurants = calculate_restaurant_rating(restaurant)
     write_restaurants("data.csv", rated_restaurants)

     # Or the ugly version of the same...
     write_restaurants("data.csv", 
       calculate_restaurant-rating(
         execute_search(
           get_location_list(),
           SEARCH_ENGINES
         )
       )
     )
  ```

  Having this functions defined would allow for your script to be used as a module in its logical parts, and you gather and manipulate the data according to different needs presenting it self. And still you could call it as a script to do a single search.